# Unable to use some attributes in my table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have this reviews table that has a user_id column in it, to see what user created it.

Heres the controller of my review: https://github.com/Veske/form/blob/ryhm/app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb

You can navigate around there if more info is needed.

But the problem here is that.. I am trying to display all the reviews on the index page.

Code looks like this:

```
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
    <tr>
        <td align="left"><%= link_to review.heading.capitalize, review, class: "black" %></td>
        <td align="left"><%= link_to review.user.name, review.user, class: "black" %></td>  
    <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(@user) %>
        <td>
            <%= link_to "Delete this review", review, method: :delete, class: "black", data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
        </td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
 <% end %>
```

The review.user.name, review.user should correctly show the name of the user that created it and also make it clickable as a link.

I have all the associations made in models (belongs_to :user has_many :reviews and etc)

Where is the problem here?

Comment: Closing this, it randomly started working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the named route `user_path(review.user)` to get the link to user

```
<td align="left"><%= link_to review.user.name, user_path(review.user), class: "black" %></td>
```

Comment: Works now, even with my previous version. I dont know why the error kept popping before.